# HP255 G6 Notebook PC help needed

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

I have been given by our company a laptop computer that they have retired but comes without a hard drive. Is it possible to get a imaged hard drive and just insert it of do I need to by a unimaged hard drive and all the software needed?

Comment: You can install some storage (SSD preferably) and then install the OS and additional software of your choice.

Comment: It comes without a hard drive likely in part because the software on it is not yours. You can install your own drive (should be SSD as noted) and then get a Windows license and install Windows, or, install Linux, at your pleasure.

Comment: What OS did the laptop come with?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to purchase a hard drive and install an operating system. You won't be able to buy a pre-imaged hard drive.

When shopping for a hard drive, you can check the specs of your laptop [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05478271). You'll need a SATA drive (preferably an SSD). If you're looking at an M.2 drive, make sure it is a SATA M.2 drive and not an NVME M.2 drive.